# How to fix auto call rejection issue in Android 8.0.0

Tags: auto-reject

One of the important number is getting automatically rejected. How can i fix this?
Samsung J7 Duos
Android 8.0.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Check your phone's Blacklist.

Check whether that important number has somehow got inside the blacklist or not. Any number in the blacklist will be automatically rejected without notifying you.